# Бизнесмен и бизнесвумен

Tags: иностранные-слова

Слово "бизнесмен" стало нарицательным, и уже никто не задумывается над тем, что это по-английски значит "деловой человек". Но как быть с деловыми женщинами? "Man" по-английски как "мужчина", так и "человек". И как все-таки говорить о женщине? Есть слово "бизнесвумен" или "безнеследи", или "безнесменша"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Бизнесвумен/бизнеследи уже фиксируется словарями, даже без указания на разговорность.
Вопрос - в употребительности слова. Нужно ли деловую женщину каждый раз попрекать её полом, да еще на буржуйский манер? Думаю, нет.

Бизнесменша - плохо, хотя у современных носителней языка эта семантика изрядно стерлась, но все-таки "бизнесменша" означает жену бизнесмена, а не женщину-безнесмена. Скорее уж "бизнесменка", как спортсменка или бушменка (бушмен - человек из кустов).

Вообще с этими "менами" и "меншами" какой-то абсурд имеет место. Какими-то англорусскими пуристами нам предписано не использовать "менов" по отношению к женщинам, потому, дескать, что в английском это невозможно. И это при том, что на голубом глазу мы называем женщину полицейским или того хуже - заведующим.

Кажется, последним, пытавшимся бороться, был Ф.Ф. Преображенский: "Я понимаю вашу иронию, профессор, мы сейчас уйдем. Только я, как заведующий культотделом дома... — Заведующая. — Заведующая." (МАБ)

ЗЫ Вспоминаются "Помпадуры и помпадурши". Как пример того, как же все-таки остёр на язык был Михаил Евграфович. Если вспомнить ещё, что самым известным "помпадуром" была как раз женщина...

Comment: Половая (гендерная?) недифференцированность некоторых наименований используется в занимательных задачах: хирург или профессор оказываются женщиной. Если  прикажут говорить "хирургиня" или "профессорка", они потеряют смысл... )))

Comment: Мартин Гарднер, "Математическая смесь"? ;)
Задачки-то переводные, наши бы до такого не садизма додумались. на английском никому и в голову не придет задумываться о гендерной идентификации хирурга.

Comment: С первым абзацем полностью согласна! Тоже считаю подчеркивание пола дурным тоном!

Answer (score 1):

Конечно - "бизнесменша"! В РУССКОМ языке женский род образуется ТОЛЬКО от мужского рода путем добавления суффиксов и окончаний. А как там в английском - нам должно быть глубоко наплевать!!! Если мы  пока ещё не оккупированный народ.